# Declaration of Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Vectors size dynamically, so why is this giving a seg fault:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> vectorOfInts;

    vectorOfInts[0] = 3;
}
```

What I'm trying to actually do is declare a vector in a class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Directory{
    public:
        string name;
        int maxIndex;
        vector<Directory> subDirectories;

        void addSubdirectory(string x){
            Directory newSubdirectory(x);
            subDirectories[maxIndex++] = newSubdirectory;
        }

        Directory(string x){
            name = x;
            maxIndex = 0;
        }
};

int main(){
    Directory root("root");
    root.addSubdirectory("games");
}
```

But this also gives a seg fault.

Comment: try use vector<int>::push_back().. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

with vector you have to use the functions of vector class

Comment: but I see so many examples online doing it the way I'm trying to do it here.

Comment: I think that it's work if the vector already in the wanted size...

Comment: Yes they do when you use them properly.

Answer (score 5):

Vectors don't resize entirely automatically. You use `push_back` or `resize` to change the size of a vector at run-time, but the vector will *not* automatically resize itself based on the index you use--if you index beyond its current size, you get undefined behavior.

In your demo code, you could do something like this:

```
vector<int> vectorOfInts(1);

vectorOfInts[0] = 3;
```

Alternatively, since you're just adding `3` to the end of the existing data (or nonexistent data, in this case) you could just use `push_back` (or `emplace_back`):

```
vector<int> vectorOfInts;
vectorOfInts.push_back(3);
```

It looks like the same basic approach will work with your real code as well. It also simplifies things a bit, since you don't need to explicitly track the maxIndex as you've done.

Comment: Thanks. it works with push_back. Many bad examples online had led me astray

Comment: Fourth or fifth time seeing this question in the last week. Don't read "examples online": learn from a reputable C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

A default-constructed vector has no elements (i.e.  its `size()` returns zero).

The `operator[]` does not check if it is supplied a valid index, and gives undefined behaviour if supplied an invalid index.    It does not resize the vector.   A vector with size zero has no valid indices.

That combination explains your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The seg fault, come from the fact that you try to acces an element that does not exist. When you use operator [ ], be sure that you already alocate memory for this element using resize, push_back, emplace_back...

To make your code work, just replace this

```
void
addSubdirectory(string x)
{
    Directory newSubdirectory(x);
    subDirectories[maxIndex++] = newSubdirectory;
}
```

by

```
void
addSubdirectory(string x)
{
    subDirectories.emplace_back(x); // c++11
                                   // else subDirectories.push_back(Directory(x));
}
```

and you don't need the maxIndex, you can have it using the size method: subDirectories.size() - 1.